# How to call one jquery method from another?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I am new to jquery. How do I call a jquery function from another function. What am I doing wrong below?

```
$('#search').bind({

//  focus: function(){ alert('focused');},
    keyup: callAjax,      // call CallAjax function
});

function callAjax(){
    $.ajax({
       // perform something here
    });
}
```

How to call `callAjax` function on `keyup` event?

Answer (score 2):

what you want is probably this ?:

```
     $('#search').keyup(function() {
        callAjax();
     });
```

or you can try this:

```
$('#search').bind('keyup', function() {
     callAjax();
});
```

When the button with ID search is 'on-key-up', this event handler will invoke callAjax..

Comment: thx all..
solved..

used the below code:

<code>
$('#search').bind({click: function(){alert('click');}, keyup: callAjax});

function callAjax(){ $.ajax({url: 'attach.html'});
</code>

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
keyup: function() {
           callAjax();
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#search').bind('keyup', callAjax);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6G58X/

Comment: yup.. the above did work.. but how to make an actual ajax call "$.ajax" instead of an alert inside callAjax()? 

 $.ajax({ url: 'ajax/test.html', success: function(data) { $('.result').html(data); alert('Load was performed.'); } });

Answer (score 1):

For me all the code works well:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function callAjax(){ alert('callAjax'); /* call whatever you want here */ }

$(function(){
    $('#search').bind({click: function(){alert('click');}, keyup: callAjax});
});
</script>
```

Comment: yup.. the above did work.. 
but how to make an actual ajax call "$.ajax" instead of an alert inside callAjax()?
'code'
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
'code'